# Programmatically set drawCircle on a per value basis on LineChart

Tags: mpandroidchart

Is there a way to toggle drawCircle on individual data points? From the documentation it appears you can only enable this at the dataset level. I'm trying to draw circles for the min/max of a dataset.

If there isn't a way to draw circles on individual data points another workaround I've tried implementing has been to create a second dataset and only plot the corresponding X index and min/max Y value; every other value is set small enough that it is not visible in the viewport. The only problem here is I can't seem to plot both datasets without overwriting the first dataset's background fill.